# How to send html email with mailgun?

Tags: mailgun

I would like to test an html email with mailgun using curl. The following comes from their documentation:

```
 curl -s --user 'api:(my api key)' \
 https://api.mailgun.net/v3/my domain/messages \
 -F from='User <me@mydomainname>' \
 -F to='me@example.com' \
 -F cc='me@example.com' \
 -F bcc='me@example.com' \
 -F subject='Hello' \
 -F text='Testing' \
 --form-string html='<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>..... MY INLINE HTML HERE.....</html>'
```

It doesn't send the message with **--form-string html**. Should there be another way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

worked with using **curl -sv** instead of **curl -s**

```
curl -sv --user 'api:YOUR API HERE' \
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR DOMAIN HERE.mailgun.org/messages \
-F from='Excited User <mailgun@YOUR DOMAIN HERE.mailgun.org>' \
-F to=you@example.com \
-F to=you@example.com \
-F subject='Hello' \
-F text='Testing' \
--form-string html='HTML HERE'
```

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. You are setting a `verbose` and a `silent` flag. Were you simply suppressing output with `-s` and thinking it didn't work?